# GRE Question : pair that expresses relationship similar to original pair

Tags: gre

[image: Image of test paper]

> **Frugal : miserly ::** ...
>
> 1. confident : arrogant
> 2. courageous : pugnacious
> 3. famous : aggressive
> 4. rash : foolhardy
> 5. quiet : timid

Option 1  (A) was the answer. Can someone explain the logic ?

Comment: First look up the terms in a dictionary, you should then see a pattern. If you cannot, edit your answer, share your research, and users will be more inclined to answer. P.S Not my downvote, but my comment helps to  explain it.

Comment: You're in luck. Someone answered.

Comment: @shrey **ELU is not a test-answering service.** Although you have hints here about how to work out this question, you **must** show your own working in future questions.

Comment: Frugal and miserly literally mean the same thing, however the connotation is different, good and bad respectively. Of all the answers only A has words that also literally mean the same thing with differing connotations.

Comment: "Frugal" is a quality, while "Miserly" is a vice, the 2 terms referering to expenses.

"Confident" is a quality, while "arrogant" is a vice both refering to "self-confidence".

In the other pairs, you can't find this **quality/vice** association. –

Answer (score 1):

YASGQ (Yet another stupid GRE question -- theirs, not yours).

Frugality is a desire not to waste money, and behavior that accords with this desire; penny pinching in a virtuous sense. Miserly is stingy, frugality taken to an extreme, a character flaw.

Famous is not a character trait and can be eliminated. Rash: foolhardy are synonyms, the latter not a more extreme version of the former, both flaws. Eliminated.

Quiet: timid would work.  Confident: arrogant would work.

Is there any difference between the two?

It comes down to how we understand "quiet".  Is it a virtue?

She's quiet but not timid.

She's confident but not arrogant.